# Find the minimum number of shipments between two countries to minimize the cost of the system

Tags: recursion, combinations, dynamic-programming, brute-force

Let's suppose transportation between two countries. We have a list of containers with different weights. Our goal is to minimize the number of shipments between two countries to minimize the cost of the system.

In this problem, our ships have a limited capacity to load containers for each shipment. For Example

Total Weight = 80 and list of countries countries = [19, 29, 43, 45, 32, 22, 51, 65, 31, 13, 62]

Here is the code i've written so for

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def powerset(list_name):
    s = list(list_name)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

A = list(cargo.values())
#A.append(19)
print(A)
res = []
for x in powerset(sorted(A)):
    if sum(x)==80:
        if x not in res:
            res.append(x)       
print(res)
```

And I got the output as:

```
[(29, 51), (13, 22, 45), (19, 29, 32)]
```

Here 29 has occurred twice which shouldn't happen and i want to find the remaining possible combinations which should give the overall output as 5.

Comment: "list of countries countries"? do you mean "list of container weights"?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a fix for your code which will make the shipment exactly 80:

```
from itertools import combinations


def find_shipments(containers, max_weight):
    # Get all possible combinations of containers
    all_combinations = []
    for i in range(1, len(containers) + 1):
        all_combinations.extend(list(combinations(containers, i)))

    # Filter out the combinations with total weight exceeding max_weight
    valid_combinations = [comb for comb in all_combinations if sum(comb) == max_weight]

    # Return the valid combinations
    return valid_combinations


containers = [19, 29, 43, 45, 32, 22, 51, 65, 31, 13, 62]
max_weight = 80

shipments = find_shipments(containers, max_weight)

print(shipments)
```

This code would solve your problem with `29` which occurred twice. Here is the output:

`[(29, 51), (19, 29, 32), (45, 22, 13)]`

But you still didn't ship all the containers, so here is the fix:

```
def find_shipments(containers, max_weight):
    # Sort the containers in descending order of weight
    containers = sorted(containers, reverse=True)

    # Initialize variables
    shipments = []

    while containers:
        # Select the largest container that can fit in the shipment
        shipment = [containers.pop(0)]

        while containers:
            next_container = containers[0]

            # If the next container can fit in the shipment, add it
            if sum(shipment) + next_container <= max_weight:
                shipment.append(containers.pop(0))
            # Otherwise, break the loop and start a new shipment
            else:
                break

        # Add the shipment to the list of shipments
        shipments.append(tuple(shipment))

    # Return the shipments
    return shipments


containers = [19, 29, 43, 45, 32, 22, 51, 65, 31, 13, 62]
max_weight = 80

shipments = find_shipments(containers, max_weight)

print(shipments)
```

Which outputs as below:

```
[(65,), (62,), (51,), (45,), (43, 32), (31, 29), (22, 19, 13)]
```